# Transpose columns to rows using excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel sheet looks like this:
Each "row" like row1 and row2 has a list of items, config, qty, and "rows" are sharing same "position".

```
+----------+---------+------------------+-------+---------+------------------+-------+
|          |     row1                           |       row2                         |
+----------+---------+------------------+-------+---------+------------------+-------+
|position  | item    | Configuration    | qty   | item    | Configuration    | qty   |
+----------+---------+------------------+-------+---------+------------------+-------+
| 1        | Spaced  |  | Spaced        | 0.00  | Spaced  |  | Spaced        | 0.00  |
| 2        | NoFiber |  | NoFiber       | 0.00  | NoFiber |  | NoFiber       | 0.00  |
| 3        | NoFiber |  | NoFiber       | 0.00  | NoFiber |  | NoFiber       | 0.00  |
| 4        | Empty   | inla | Empty     | 0.00  | Empty   | inkz | Empty     | 0.00  |
| 5        | Empty   | inla | Empty     | 0.00  | Empty   | inkz | Empty     | 0.00  |
| 6        | Empty   | inkq | Empty     | 0.00  | Empty   | inkp | Empty     | 0.00  |
| 7        | Empty   | inkq | Empty     | 0.00  | Empty   | inkp | Empty     | 0.00  |
| 8        | Empty   | inkf | Empty     | 0.00  | Empty   | inke | Empty     | 0.00  |
| 9        | Empty   | inkf | Empty     | 0.00  | Empty   | inke | Empty     | 0.00  |
| 10       | 98211   | inht inid | Iota | 19.23 | 98210   | inhs inic | Iota | 19.23 |
| 11       | 98209   | ingy inhj | Iota | 19.23 | 98208   | ingx inhi | Iota | 19.23 |
| 12       | Spaced  | ingo | Spaced    | 0.00  | Spaced  | ingn | Spaced    | 0.00  |
| 13       | 99186   | ingo | Ibis      | 54.79 | 99185   | ingn | Ibis      | 54.79 |
+----------+---------+------------------+-------+---------+------------------+-------+
```

I want to use macro to transpose to look like this.

```
+----------+---------+------+--------+------------------+
| position |  bbnum  | row  |  qty   |  Configuration   |
+----------+---------+------+--------+------------------+
|        1 | Spaced  | row1 | 0      |  | Spaced        |
|        2 | NoFiber | row1 | 0      |  | NoFiber       |
|        3 | NoFiber | row1 | 0      |  | NoFiber       |
|        4 | Empty   | row1 | 0      | inla | Empty     |
|        5 | Empty   | row1 | 0      | inla | Empty     |
|        6 | Empty   | row1 | 0      | inkq | Empty     |
|        7 | Empty   | row1 | 0      | inkq | Empty     |
|        8 | Empty   | row1 | 0      | inkf | Empty     |
|        9 | Empty   | row1 | 0      | inkf | Empty     |
|       10 | 98211   | row1 | 19.228 | inht inid | Iota |
|       11 | 98209   | row1 | 19.228 | ingy inhj | Iota |
|       12 | Spaced  | row1 | 0      | ingo | Spaced    |
|       13 | 99186   | row1 | 54.791 | ingo | Ibis      |
|        1 | Spaced  | row2 | 0      |  | Spaced        |
|        2 | NoFiber | row2 | 0      |  | NoFiber       |
|        3 | NoFiber | row2 | 0      |  | NoFiber       |
|        4 | Empty   | row2 | 0      | inkz | Empty     |
|        5 | Empty   | row2 | 0      | inkz | Empty     |
|        6 | Empty   | row2 | 0      | inkp | Empty     |
|        7 | Empty   | row2 | 0      | inkp | Empty     |
|        8 | Empty   | row2 | 0      | inke | Empty     |
|        9 | Empty   | row2 | 0      | inke | Empty     |
|       10 | 98210   | row2 | 19.23  | inhs inic | Iota |
|       11 | 98208   | row2 | 19.23  | ingx inhi | Iota |
|       12 | Spaced  | row2 | 0      | ingn | Spaced    |
|       13 | 99185   | row2 | 54.79  | ingn | Ibis      |

+----------+---------+------+--------+------------------+
```

How can I make it happen using macro since there are ~20 "rows" and ~40 "positions" in my sheet. I'm new to macro so hopefully I can make this automated otherwise I'm copying and pasting all of them manually.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the first row of your data after the headers?  Also, for the Configuration, is that two columns merged sometimes? What's the the layout.

Comment: It seems that you are not transposing, but rather adding a range below another range: is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work over as many columns as you have.  As long as there are 4 columns in each Row group.
**Explanation:**

Get the last row of the source sheet and the last column.  Identify how many columns are in each group.
Loop through the column groups one "ROW#" (your label) at a time, through all rows deep.
Copy the data to the target sheet, in the format you want
Go to next Column Group

**Setup:**
You will need to create a new Sheet.
example: "Target".

Then set up the header rows.
example: data starts on row 2 of Target Sheet

Make sure to check the code to see where the columns and rows begin on the source sheet.

Set the name of your source sheet in the code.

**TESTED:**

```
Sub ColumnCopy()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim colBase As Long

Dim tRow As Long
Dim source As String
Dim target As String
    
    source = "Sheet1"       'Set your source sheet here
    target = "Target"       'Set the Target sheet name
    
    tRow = 2                'Define the start row of the target sheet
    
    'Get Last Row and Column
    lastRow = Sheets(source).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = Sheets(source).Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    tRow = 2
    colBase = 2
    Do While colBase < lastCol
        For iRow = 3 To lastRow
            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, 1) = Sheets(source).Cells(iRow, 1)           'Position
            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, 2) = Sheets(source).Cells(iRow, colBase)      'bbnum
            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, 3) = Sheets(source).Cells(1, colBase)         'Getting The Row#, from Row 1
            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, 4) = Sheets(source).Cells(iRow, colBase + 3)  'qty
            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, 5) = Sheets(source).Cells(iRow, colBase + 1)  'Configuration Col 1
            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, 6) = Sheets(source).Cells(iRow, colBase + 2)  'Configuration Col 2
            tRow = tRow + 1
        Next iRow
        colBase = colBase + 4       'Add 4 to the Column Base.  This shifts the loop over to the next Row set.
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image: Source]
[image]

edit:corrected typo in code